# xdebug not cooperating with php (phpStorm) anymore

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I had xdebug working with PhpStorm, now it is not. I ran brew doctor while trying to resolve problems around installing mcrypt, and unfortunately tried to follow brew doctor's instructions.

php -i from the command line shows me a lot of things about xdebug, some of which indicate it isn't set up right. Relevant (i think) output looks like:

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.4.0
IDE Key => rgrossetest

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

If I put

```
phpinfo();
die();
```

at the top of the site index.php I don't see any of that. The php versions are slightly off as well-- though dev in the cage next to me says that doesn't matter. All I see in that output that mentions xdebug is under "PHP Variables":

```
_REQUEST["XDEBUG_SESSION"]  phpStorm
```

If I go into my php.ini (the one reflected in my command line output) I had a line:

```
zend_extension = xdebug.so
```

which I first changed to

```
zend_extension = /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
```

after creating dirs /extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ in order to put xdebug.so in there so it would stop complaining. That didn't work, but commenting it out did. With that line uncommented command php -v says:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.5.34 (cli) (built: Mar 31 2016 14:37:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

and if I comment that line out then no errors. No debugging either. I can turn it on in Chrome, start listening in phpStorm, but no response. Now I can see that first of all the IDE Key looks wrong in the command line php -i output:

```
IDE Key => rgrossetest
```

(though I can also later see that it doesn't seem defined at all? wtf?):

```
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
```

So, where is this module? What module is being loaded/not being loaded? I don't know who is controlling what here.

Muchas gracias for any insight,
R

======edit: adding phpinfo() header =======
    php -i
    PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

```
Warning: Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.5.34

System => Darwin rgrovembpxx.cnet.cnwk 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Mon Jan 11 18:48:35 PST 2016; root:xnu-2782.50.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Build Date => Mar 31 2016 14:36:26
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34' '--localstatedir=/usr/local/var' '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d' '--mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/share/man' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-dba' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zip' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext' '--with-iconv-dir=/usr' '--with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg' '--with-kerberos=/usr' '--with-libedit' '--with-mhash' '--with-ndbm=/usr' '--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng' '--with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-readline=/usr/local/opt/readline' '--without-gmp' '--without-snmp' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--libexecdir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.34/libexec' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--disable-debug' '--with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-user=_www' '--with-fpm-group=_www' '--with-curl' '--with-xsl=/usr' '--with-ldap' '--with-ldap-sasl=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--disable-opcache' '--enable-pcntl' '--without-pear' '--enable-dtrace' '--enable-zend-signals'
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini

PHP API => 20121113
PHP Extension => 20121212
Zend Extension => 220121212
Zend Extension Build => API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20121212,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => enabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

=====MORE php -i output, now without the "already loaded" errors: =======

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.4.0
IDE Key => phpStorm

Supported protocols => Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol => $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 1 => 1
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => phpStorm => phpStorm
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => On => On
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /var/tmp/ => /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Comment: So far I see nothing to do with actual PhpStorm ... except the fact that you simply unable to enable/configure xdebug in your php.ini (for whatever reason). To start: 1) your OS 2) provide header of `phpinfo()` out put 3) what php.ini you are editing and what xdebug settings it has

Comment: My OS is OS X Yosemite, 10.10.5

Comment: Are you running your own install of apache by any chance ? (as in not the brain dead version that ships with osx ?

Comment: Thanks-- I am editing that php.ini, and have got that piece happening now, I believe: I needed to edit the php.ini file like so: zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-xdebug/xdebug.so" and now the Php IDE key has changed. LazyOne, I added the phpinfo() output above. Again, this is actually output from php -i from the command line-- putting phpinfo() into my index.php still gives me no xdebug section.

Comment: It is my own apache install, yes, not the stock osx.

Comment: ok that explains probably your version error too. You need to nuke that permanently, and put in your own apache to start on boot/login. Even if you killall apache, it restarts the shipping version before you have time to start your own. `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` kills permanently the shipping version.

Comment: OK- did that, but I don't notice any effect. I should note that I did have this running for quite a while under this os without having to kill any other apache versions.

Comment: I tried adding a configuration in phpStorm-- I think I do need a debug configuration there. So set up a 'PHP Built-in Web Server', and since we're using symlinks tried several different document root values, because I'm not sure exactly what phpStorm will consider doc root (where the source files are, or where index.php is? Where the symlink points or where the actual file is?) Anyway, trying to start debugging in phpStorm I get the message "[Thu Apr 14 11:09:35 2016] PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Also, when I stop debugging in phpStorm it quits with the message: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
PHP 5.5.34 Development Server started at Thu Apr 14 11:09:35 2016
Listening on http://localhost:9000
Document root is /content/data/www.redacted.com/cbs-mvc
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: *"Thanks-- I am editing that php.in"* Which "that"?`/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini` -- this one? Accordingly to your output, xdebug settings most actually stored in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini`. This may also explain the `Module 'xdebug' already loaded in` message -- you are trying to load the same module twice in different files. Look into this ... when you fix this -- post `xdebug` section of `phpinfo();` output.

Comment: 2) Since you are trying to debug via browser -- please collect `phpinfo()` output from browser as well. In your particular case it *may* not make any difference (at least your info suggests this) .. but on some systems Apache will use separate config file as compared to to the CLI.

Comment: Yes, I am editing /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini -- I deleted the xdebug lines in /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini and am not getting those already loaded messages. i will once again add the php -i output above-- and I think you are right about the phpinfo() output from browser, which has NO xdebug information.

Comment: So .. get `phpinfo()` output in the browser -- see top header table and find what ini files where used and make xdebug work there. Once done -- try debugging. If still nothing -- collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . At the same time -- provide results of `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

Got this working by making sure I was editing the php.ini used by apache in this instance.

1) Check the output (thanks LazyOne!) of phpinfo() from apache. In this case I'm seeing /etc -- so check your default php.ini, which may not be the same you see from command line.

2) Add xdebug config. It will look something like:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_host= "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey = "phpStorm"
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

3) Restart apache. You should be good.

Thanks for all the help.